# Install a manpage manually on Debian-based OS

Tags: debian, manpage

For a little Python script "mytool" I wrote a Manpage that I want to install manually (no OS package) on a Debian based OS.
How do I do that?

I tried gzipping the manpage and copied it to several locations (/usr/share/mytool, /usr/share/man8, /usr/local/man/man8), but the manpage does not show up if I run "man mytool".
Do I need to refresh the manpages somehow so that man finds the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install -g 0 -o 0 -m 0644 mytool.8 /usr/local/man/man8/

Comment: If I do that and run "man mytool" man still complains "No manual entry for mytool". Do I need to refresh the manpages somehow?

Comment: Got it. Did not know that the section of the manpage must be the same section as the target where I copy it. So if manpage has section "1", it needs to go to /usr/local/man/man1. If it has secion "8", it needs to go to /usr/local/man/man8.